# Angular 5 redirects home in case of http post error

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a simple service that performs a post http request:

```
@Injectable() export class AuthService {

    ......
    ......
    attemptAuth(user: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

        const credentials = { user:user, password:password };
        return this.http.post(this.authUrl, credentials)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }
    ......
    ......
    errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

the attemptAuthFunction is called by a component in the way below:

```
this.authService.attemptAuth(user, password).subscribe(
  data => {
    ........
  },
  error => {
    ........
  }
);
```

Everything is fine except when i submit a wrong user/password: in case of error there is an automatic redirection to the web app home page instead of remaining in the current page and executing the code inside the error => .. section.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` statement?

Comment: A redirect? Then I assume you also used the Angular routing. It must have been used somewhere in your application, because there would be no reason to do a redirect. Can we see more of the code?

Comment: I use the angular routing but there is no usage of router when i call the auth service. What can i show you in order to understand better? Thanks for your help

Comment: One issue I see is, that you're already catching the error in your declaration of your service, but then expect that your error callback will work. EDIT: My mistake, an absolutely bogus statement of mine. It actually works... I would suggest you upload your project so others can analyze your code. I'm pretty certain that you are programatically navigating.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately i'm not allowed to share my whole project. Is there another way to share only some settings?

Comment: Could you at least show the entire service code and the code where the service is being used? Also, I would like to see your routing configuration.

Comment: Try to find a class which implements `HttpInterceptor` interface. You'r magic probably located there.

Comment: guys you were right! i had an httpinterceptor that was navigating programmatically... thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be to not define an error handler:

```
attemptAuth(user: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const credentials = { user:user, password:password };
    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, credentials)
        ; // REMOVE THIS: .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

If the errors won't be thrown as an exception, they should be given to your error handler of the subscription.

Comment: thanks for your help. That part of the code is effectively not useful since the error handler simply throws the exception.
Anyway, I still have the same routing issue (unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was an http interceptor calling a navigation programmatically. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as the right one in a few days. So it doesn't appear among the unsolved ones! Aside that, happy coding!